# Nobel Prize winning literature translated to Esperanto

Tags: literature

Which books that won the Noble Prize for Literature have been translated to Esperanto? For those that have been, where are they available from?

Answer (score 3):

*Cent jaroj da soleco*, by Gabriel García Márquez who was awarded the 1982 Nobel Prize for Literature. You can buy it through *Elektronikaj Esperantolibroj* ([digital version](http://www.bitlibroj.com/tradukitaesperantoliteraturo/tradukitaprozoesperanto.html)), *Mondial* ([paper version](http://librejo.com/tradukita.html#cent)), or *Universala Esperanto Asocio* ([paper version](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=4379)).

> *Cent jaroj da soleco* (1967) estas la ĉefverko de la nobelpremiita kolombia aŭtoro Gabriel García Márquez (1927-2014) kaj unu el la plej
>   famaj verkoj de la hispanlingva kaj la monda literaturo.
>
> La tradukon el la hispana en Esperanton de *Cent jaroj da soleco*
>   majstre realigis [Fernando de Diego](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_de_Diego) (1919-2005). La Esperanta
>   versio aperis unue en 1992 ĉe la eldonejo Fonto en Brazilo kaj estas
>   nun publikigita de Mondial en la tria eldono.

Comment: Thanks, this is incidentally my personal favorite book, though I don't own an Esperanto translation yet. It also was my reason for posting the question, so I'm curious if there are any other books on this list.